# SQL: how to select multiple rows given condition

Tags: sql

```
userid       pageid
123          100
123          101
456          101
567          100
```

I want to return all the `userid` with `pageid` 100 AND 101, should give me 123 only.  This is probably super easy but I can't figure it out!  I tried:

```
SELECT userid
FROM table_name 
WHERE pageid=100 AND pageid=101
```

But it gives me 0 results.  Any help please

Comment: You said "I want to return all the userid with pageid 100 **and** 101" but according to your sample data user 567 doesn't have a page 101... are you sure you want to return it?

Comment: good catch just edited question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No record has 2 values of `pageid`. You probably want:

```
SELECT userid
FROM table_name 
WHERE pageid=100 OR pageid=101
```

In a cleaner version, you can use:

```
SELECT userid
FROM table_name 
WHERE pageid IN (100,101)
```

**UPDATE:** Based on the question edit, Here is the answer:

```
SELECT userid
FROM table_name 
WHERE pageid IN (100,101)
GROUP BY userid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pageid) = 2
```

Explanation:

First of all, the WHERE clause filter out all data except `pageid` not equal to 101 or 102. Then, By grouping `userid`, we have a list of unique `userid` having `DISTINCT pageid = 2`, which means contain ONLY 1 `pageid = 101` and 1 `pageid = 102`

Answer (score 1):

According to your last edit you want to find all (distinct) `userid` where a `pageid` of 101 and also 101 exists. You can use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT userid
FROM TableName t1 
WHERE t1.userid=123
AND EXISTS(
  SELECT 1 FROM TableName t2
  WHERE t2.userid=t1.userid AND pageid = 100
 )
AND EXISTS(
  SELECT 1 FROM TableName t2
  WHERE t2.userid=t1.userid AND pageid = 101
 )
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/60439/9/0)</kbd>

<strike>I assume you are confusing `AND` with `OR`, this returns multiple records:</strike>

```
SELECT DISTINCT userid
FROM TableName 
WHERE pageid=100 OR pageid=101
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/60439/4/0)</kbd>

```
USERID
123
567
```

Note that i have used `DISTINCT` to remove duplicates, since you don't want them.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT userid
FROM Table1 
WHERE pageid IN (100,101)
GROUP BY userid HAVING COUNT(distinct pageid) = 2;
```

**[SAMPLE FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e03e6/6)**

Answer (score 1):

You could use or instead of and

```
Select userid
from table
where pageid=100 or pageid=101
```

If you only want to get distinct results you can use the distinct keyword.  For example

```
Select distinct userid
from table
where pageid=100 or pageid=101
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a given `userid` can't have the same `pageid` more than once:

```
SELECT userid
FROM   table_name
WHERE  pageid IN (100, 101)
GROUP
    BY userid
HAVING Count(*) = 2 /* number of items to match */
```

Comment: Your query will fail when there duplication in the table see http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d420a/2, use `DISTINCT` in `COUNT`.

Comment: @snyder correct, it will. I assumed that the table had the necessary constraints and that's why I prefaced my answer with the comment I did.